# Problema com Card Flip JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Copiei o seguinte código aqui:
https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/LmWozd

Ele funciona bem, o problema é quando duplico o card, ou uso as mesmas classes em outro card, ai não ativa o JS que faz o Flip no Card. Alguém pode me ajudar por gentileza?

EDIT
Aqui meu código com problema:
https://codepen.io/theorestivo/pen/ExaxwPY

Somente o primeiro Card da Flip, o segundo não.

Answer (score 2):

Use o `querySelectorAll()` para regastar todas ocorrências de `.card` e depois itere sobre essas ocorrências com o `forEach()`, exemplo:

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card'); // Pegar todas ocorrências
cards.forEach((card) => { // Iterar sobre elas adicionando o listener
  card.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
    card.classList.toggle('is-flipped');
  });
})
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 40px 0;
  perspective: 600px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: center right;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.card.is-flipped {
  transform: translateX(-100%) rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.card__face--front {
  background: red;
}

.card__face--back {
  background: blue;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene scene--card">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__face card__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="card__face card__face--back">back</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Click card to flip.</p>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu super certo. Mas porque as pessoas negativaram minha pergunta? Sou novo aqui, qual o problema de tirar dúvida? Obrigado!!